# RecyclerView and OnItemTouchListener with Firebase, no FirebaseListAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

i'm stuck with a certain problem.

So i want to get the id (maybe with getKey()) from the clicked Item in my RecyclerView to pass it to the next activity.

I have set up an adapter. I've tried a lot of solutions, but obviously nothing worked. 
With this solution, i get **all** keys from my database. But i want only the clicked one.

This is my normal activity:

```
public class searchRecipeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText searchRecipe;

RecyclerView showList;

FirebaseUser user;

DatabaseReference ref;

FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

Context context;

ArrayList<String> durationList;
ArrayList<String> nameList;
//ArrayList<String> recipeList;
ArrayList<String> ingList;

SearchAdapterRecipe searchAdapterRecipe;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_recipe);

    searchRecipe = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_txt);

    showList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.listview_txt);

    user = firebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    durationList = new ArrayList<>();
    nameList = new ArrayList<>();
    ingList = new ArrayList<>();

    showList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    showList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    showList.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));

    searchRecipe.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            if(!s.toString().isEmpty()){
                setAdapter(s.toString());
            } else {
                nameList.clear();
                ingList.clear();
                durationList.clear();
                showList.removeAllViews();
            }
        }
    });

}

private void setAdapter(final String searchedString) {

    ref.child("recipes").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            nameList.clear();
            ingList.clear();
            durationList.clear();
            showList.removeAllViews();

            int count = 0;

            for (final DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                String uid = snapshot.getKey();
                String name = snapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                String zutaten = snapshot.child("zutat").getValue(String.class);
                String dauer = snapshot.child("dauer").getValue(String.class);

                if (name.toLowerCase().contains(searchedString.toLowerCase())){

                    nameList.add(name);
                    ingList.add(zutaten);
                    durationList.add(dauer);
                    count++;

                } else if (dauer.toLowerCase().contains(searchedString.toLowerCase())){

                    nameList.add(name);
                    ingList.add(zutaten);
                    durationList.add(dauer);
                    count++;

                } else if (zutaten.toLowerCase().contains(searchedString.toLowerCase())){

                    nameList.add(name);
                    ingList.add(zutaten);
                    durationList.add(dauer);
                    count++;

                }

                if (count == 10){

                    break;
                }



                searchAdapterRecipe = new SearchAdapterRecipe(searchRecipeActivity.this, nameList, ingList, durationList);
                showList.setAdapter(searchAdapterRecipe);


                showList.addOnItemTouchListener(
                        new RecyclerItemClickListener(context, showList ,new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                            @Override public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

                                String rID = snapshot.getKey();

                                //Syso
                                System.out.println("ID: " + rID);

                                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), showRecipeActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("recipeID", rID);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }

                            @Override public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position) {
                                // do whatever
                            }
                        })
                );
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

and this my adapter:

```
public class SearchAdapterRecipe extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchAdapterRecipe.SearchViewHolder> {

Context context;

ArrayList<String> durationList;
ArrayList<String> nameList;
ArrayList<String> ingList;

class SearchViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView name, zutat, dauer;

    public SearchViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.recipeName);
        zutat = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.recipeZutat);
        dauer = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.recipeDauer);

    }
}

public SearchAdapterRecipe(Context context, ArrayList<String> durationList, ArrayList<String> nameList, ArrayList<String> ingList) {

    this.context = context;
    this.durationList = durationList;
    this.nameList = nameList;
    this.ingList = ingList;
}



@Override
public SearchAdapterRecipe.SearchViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.search_list_item, parent, false);
    return new SearchAdapterRecipe.SearchViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(SearchViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.name.setText(nameList.get(position));
    holder.zutat.setText(ingList.get(position));
    holder.dauer.setText(durationList.get(position));

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return nameList.size();
}
```

}

Maybe you can help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the `addOnItemTouchListener` I would do

```
String rID  = *yourList*.get(position).getKey();
```